# How to add required validation on single select drop-down autocomplete on save button

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using Angular Material mat-select component with autocomplete, even though I have added required validation, it is not working.

**here is the code for single select drop-down autocomplete** :

```
<input matInput placeholder="Select an option" [matAutocomplete]="auto1" [formControl]="filteredOption" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" **required** ngDefaultControl (blur)="checkReq()">
<mat-autocomplete #auto1="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayOpt">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let opt of filteredOpt | async" [value]="option?.id === selectedValue?.id ? selectedValue : opt">
    <span>{{opt}}</span>
    </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

**Then html for save button**

`<button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="save()"[disabled]="editForm.form.invalid || isSaving">Save</button>`

In drop-down code, we are also adding **required** but it's not working.

Comment: can you show us your code?

Comment: If i were you i would recommend you to use angular reactive forms and Validators from @angular/forms. It is easier way to control your forms in my opinion. Check this https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: Earlier it was working, it stopped working after we used autocomplete.